# sklearn patchextractor...missing elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am toying around with using python to apply various image-kernels to images; I am using sklearn.feature_extraction to create the patches, however, when I do so, it appears some of the data is missing, which will cause problems when I go back to reconstruct the image. Am I doing something wrong, or do I have to add a buffer around the image when grabbing the patches for border cases?

```
from PIL import Image
sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('a.png')
arr = np.array(img)
patches = imagePatchExtractor(patch_size=(3,3)).fit(arr).transform(arr)

>>>arr.shape
(1080, 1080, 3)
>>>patches.shape
(1164240, 3, 3)
>>>1164240/1080
1078.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to understand here:

1. `image.PatchExtractor` extracts **all possible patches** with strides of 1 in each dimension. For example, with patches of shape `(3, 3)` you will get `arr[0:3, 0:3, 0]`, then `arr[1:4, 1:4, 0]`, and so on. Hence, in general, for a patch size of `(x, y)` and image size of `(w, h)` you will get `(w-x+1)*(h-y+1)` many patches for each channel. The `-x+1` and `-y+1` is due to the patch hitting the image boundaries (there is no padding).
2. [`PatchExtractor.transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.PatchExtractor.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.PatchExtractor.transform) expects the first dimension to be the `n_samples`. So, in your case the shape should be `(1, 1080, 1080, 3)`.

Putting all this together, here is an example with a fake smaller image with one channel:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import numpy as np

# Adding the n_samples dimension with reshape.
arr = np.arange(0, 6*6*1).reshape((1, 6, 6))
print(arr)
```

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]])
```

```
# Get all possible patches.
patches = image.PatchExtractor(patch_size=(3, 3)).fit(arr).transform(arr)
print(np.shape(patches))
print(patches[0, :])
print(patches[1, :])
```

```
shape: 
   # (6-3+1) * (6-3+1) = 16
   (16, 3, 3)

patches[0, :]:
   array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
          [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
          [12., 13., 14.]])

patches[1, :]:
   array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
          [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
          [13., 14., 15.]])
```

As you can see, the result matches the explanation above. Patch 1 is displaced by one pixel to the right with respect to patch 2.

Hence, in your case with an image of shape `(1080, 1080, 3)`:

```
# You also need this reshape to add the n_samples dimension.
arr = np.arange(0, 1080*1080*3).reshape((1, 1080, 1080, 3))
patches = image.PatchExtractor(patch_size=(3, 3)).fit(arr).transform(arr)
print(np.shape(patches))
```

```
# (1080-3+1)*(1080-3+1) = 1162084
(1162084, 3, 3, 3)
```

### EDIT - patches with padding:

If you want to have the same number of patches for each pixel you could pad the image using [`np.pad()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html). Note that by default it pads all the axes, so we need to manually specify the pad amounts per-axis:

```
# Padding amount for each axis. Here: amount should be patch_size-1.
# Here, the format is (pad_before, pad_after) for each dimension.
paddings = ((0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0))
wrapped_arr = np.pad(arr, pad_width=paddings, mode='wrap')
wrapped_patches = image.PatchExtractor(patch_size=(3, 3)).fit(wrapped_arr).transform(wrapped_arr)

print(np.shape(wrapped_patches))
```

```
# 1080*1080 = 1166400
(1166400, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the response...that worked. I was able to apply an arbitrary image-kernel and then reconstruct the image from the patches...I'm almost to my goal, the only problem is the border issue. I'm surprised that the patches extractor doesn't create patches for every pixel, but simply avoids the border...is there an easy way to pad an image with numpy such that the pad "wraps around" the image? I tried using np.pad(arr, 1, 'wrap'), but it gave me a shape of (3, 1082, 1082, 5)...not what I was expecting.

Comment: @user18615293 the problem is that `np.pad()` pads every axis by default. See the edit of my answer for a solution. You need to specify manually which dimensions to pad. I put an example in my answer at the bottom.

Comment: thanks a lot...your solution was exactly what I needed.